# HTML5: Should I use h2's or h3's for content inside of an aside element?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been poking around online but I can't seem to find a definitive answer on this. Given the following HTML5 structure below, should I be using h2's or h3's inside of my aside element for content titles?

I know it's okay to use multiple h1's as long as they are inside a section and/or article element. But i'm not sure what I should do within my aside? I think I should stay away from multiple h1's in an aside but im not sure about h2's and h3's.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Heading Tags</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <header>
        <h1>Main Section</h1>
    </header>

    <article>
        <h1>Article Title 1</h1>
        <div>Some Content Here</div>
    </article>

    <article>
        <h1>Article Title 2</h1>
        <div>Some Content Here</div>
    </article>

    <article>
        <h1>Article Title 3</h1>
        <div>Some Content Here</div>
    </article>
</section>

<aside>
    <header>
        <h1>Side Bar Heading</h1>
    </header>

    <div>
        <h2>Side Content Title 1</h2>
        <div>Some Content Here</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Side Content Title 2</h2>
        <div>Some Content Here</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Side Content Title 3</h2>
        <div>Some Content Here</div>
    </div>
</aside>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should be using h2's and h3's as mini-titles per se. If you need to play around with the sizes, use CSS for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using multiple `<h1>`s on a page. The `h` tags are primarily used to dictate document structure. The [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20120103/G141) shows examples that the `h1` tag should title the page. Most states (Illinois, for example) have their own outlines on Accessibility standards. Illinois' in specific outlines that there should only ever be one `h1` tag on a page and that it's contents be similar to the `<title>` tag. While this can be, and probably will be, argued, it makes semantic sense to only use one `h1` tag and let the other 5 layers sit nested correctly.

Really, common sense plays a big role in structuring your other `h` tags. Imagine looking at your site in an 'outline mode' when you're done. Does it make sense?

For example, say you want the outline of your site to look like this:

```
Page Title

Content
 - Article
   - Sub-article
 - Article

Sidebar
 - Weather
 - Local News
```

Then this is how your heading tags should be working:

```
<header>
  <h1>My News Website</h1>
  <nav></nav>
</header>
<section>
  <article>
    <h2>Article Title</h2>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah.</p>
    <h3>Sub-heading in Article</h3>
    <p>More blah blah blah.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Article Title</h2>
    <p>Blah Blah Blah.</p>
  </article>
</section>
<aside>
  <h2>Weather</h2>
  <p>Weather information.</p>
  <h2>Local News</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>News Item</li>
    <li>News Item</li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

As long as things you want at the same level share the same heading number, then you're on the right track. Things that relate to a heading that contextually make sense to be "under" said heading should increment the heading number by one.

Lastly, you can have an outline of your completed site shown to you by using the HTLM 5 Outline. Check it out here: http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/

Comment: Actually, I believe you're encouraged to use `<h1>`s multiple times because the document treats nested `<section><h1>` headlines as an `<h2>` as of HTML5 http://html5doctor.com/your-questions-answered-6/

Comment: That's the impression I was under potench.

Comment: HTML5 does treat nested `h1`s in that way, but it is not encouraged. In fact, Matt Cutts from Google has stated that "multiple h1 elements is something Google watches for, and may penalize if the useage doesn’t make sense". While understanding it does make sense to HTML5, there are other search engines beside Google and if you want your site to be as SEO as possible, I would argue best practices is to continue working with one `h1` header per page as it is not wrong either.

Comment: From Google Webmaster Help: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIn5qJKU8VM&feature=player_embedded  TLDR; SEO algorithm prioritizes H1, using it multiple times is fine, but don't game the system

Comment: @potench - That what HTML5 says, sure, but there's a problem. Browsers don't currently implement the HTML5 outline algorithm, which probably means that the heading levels get exposed incorrectly to the accessibility API. For now, I recommend using h? elements the HTML4 way.

Comment: You should not be coding in HTML4.... that is a terrible recommendation / 10 reasons to use HTML5 / http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/24/top-10-reasons-to-use-html5-right-now/

Comment: @potench - The HTML4 way is also valid in HTML5.

Comment: I mean, while we're at it... just don't use an `<aside>` then right?

Comment: The underlying issue that we are getting away from here is accessibility. Google, and SEO, and HTML5 may all say you may use more than one `h1` element, but there is a problem with HTML5 outlining in most browsers which in turn reports that information incorrectly to JAWS or whatever assistive technologies someone may be using. As I said in my answer, this would be argued, but accessibility issues should be more important than semantic issues, especially in this case, in which using one `h1` element is not incorrect.

Comment: @potench - Why? What harm does using `<aside>` do?

Comment: @alohci it was sarcasm... I'm saying you shouldn't recommend supporting an HTML4 standard while also using an HTML5 element. Here's HTML5 doctors example markup of an `<aside>` which is treated like a section by the document and hence *should* use an `<h1>` http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/ Assuming your `<aside>` is not nested in another `<section>`

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen - While whether accessibility issues outrank semantic ones is arguable, there not need be any conflict. Your answer works well for both.

Comment: @potench - Note the last aside in the example on the page you link to. See how it uses h2. I'm just recommending to do that throughout for safety's sake.

Comment: Here's the site im currently doing work for. http://www.killsometime.com If you notice in the right column, there is an aside named "Whats Hot". Currently each link title is a h1. Judging from the arguments, im still a bit confused as to whether or not these should continue to be h1's or should be dropped down to h2's or h3's?

Comment: In my opinion, in the aside, the "What's Hot" should be an `h2` and each title under it should be an `h3`. I would do that to avoid the "more than one `h1`" scenario. However, it would be appropriate to use an `h1` for "What's Hot" and `h2`s for the title according to HTML5 spec. Regardless, the individual titles shouldn't be `h1`s.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Michael.

Answer (score 4):

According [to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines#The_HTML5_outline_algorithm):

> Sections in HTML5 can be nested. Beside the main section, defined by the  element, section limits are defined either explicitly or implicitly. Explicitly-defined sections are the content within <body>,  <section>,  <article>,  <aside>, and <nav> tags.
>
> Each section can have its own heading hierarchy. Therefore, even a nested section can have an <h1>.

So the way you've done it -- with one `<h1>` and multiple `<h2>` inside your `<aside>` -- is appropriate.

Comment: Updated MDN: Note: Nesting multiple <h1> elements in nested sectioning elements was allowed in older versions of the HTML standard. However, this was never considered a best practice and is now non-conforming.

Answer (score 0):

[State of MDN Apr 21, 2022](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#multiple_h1_elements_on_one_page):

> Using more than one  is allowed by the HTML specification, but is not considered a best practice. Using only one  is beneficial for screenreader users.
>
> The HTML specification includes the concept of an outline formed by the use of  elements. If this were implemented it would enable the use of multiple  elements, giving user agents—including screen readers—a way to understand that an  nested inside a defined section is a subheading. This functionality has never been implemented; therefore it is important to use your headings to describe the outline of your document.